# Catch exception in xunit test

Tags: c#, integration-testing, xunit.net, fact

Can I catch the exception that appears in the log but not in the test?

I performed the test and it returned the status: OK, but in the log I have:
Unexpected error publishing create package to Kafka. id = 5ec3eb81aa662c8a7c76e5e8. Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

How can I catch this exception in the test? I tried to use Try and catch (Exception) but nothing catches.

```
 [Fact]
    [DisplayTestMethodName]
    public async Task ExceptionTest()
    {
        try
        {
            var testRequest= @"{""Test1"":"1234"};
            var testRequestResp =
                await fixture.PostAsync(testRequest);
            Assert.Equal("HttpStatusCode: " + System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK, "HttpStatusCode: " + testRequestResp.StatusCode);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Assert.True(ex == null, "Exception: " + ex.Message);
        }
```

Log
[VS log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVNpu.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means you are handling the `NullReferenceException` already somewhere in your `PostAsync` method and still returning status 200. That is a design decision to swallow the error and return "OK" (hopefully you are logging it or something at least).

A different approach would be to return a 500 status instead of 200, to indicate that an internal server error has occurred - then try and address the `NullReferenceException`.

You may also choose *not* to swallow the error in you `PostAsync` method and let it bubble all the way up. In that case, you could use:

```cs
var exception = await Assert.ThrowsAsync<NullReferenceException>(() => fixture.PostAsync(testRequest));
```

(Where `testRequest` was something you knew would trigger that error)

If getting a `NullReferenceException` is expected behavior and the request is still "OK" status, then somehow catching it in your test would make no sense.

Answer (score -1):

I want to check that the exception "NullReferenceException" does not occur.
I used your advice:

```
var exception = await Assert.ThrowsAsync<NullReferenceException>(() => fixture.PostAsync(testRequest));
```

But I don't catch this exception

[image]
Where is the problem?

Comment: Yes. Like I said in my answer, that's because the exception is being swallowed inside the `PostAsync` method somewhere (probably in a `try`/`catch` block that doesn't rethrow it).

Comment: this should be a comment on the other answer (you can edit a followup in at the end of your question)